# ARC semantic issue no visible @interface for 'MKPinAnnotationView' declares the selector 'initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, xcode6, mkannotationview

Here's the code I have trying to set up the pin annotation view for the pins on my map. I'm using the default pins already available on MKPinAnnotationView.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AKNeutralPin.h" // NSObject <MKAnnotation> class

@interface ViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate>
...

@implementation

...

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[AKNeutralPin class]]) {
         MKPinAnnotationView *neutralPinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"neutral"];
         neutralPinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"neutral"];
         neutralPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
         neutralPinView.canShowCallout = YES;
         return neutralPinView;
}

return nil;
}
```

The problem is the code works perfectly fine in simulator but not on device. 
Shows error:

`ARC semantic issue no visible @interface for 'MKPinAnnotationView' declares the selector 'initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier:`.

I've checked the file path of AKNeutralPin.h and .m. They are in the right file path. Not sure what I'm missing here. Any help is much appreciated!

UPDATE: I have exported the code to .ipa file and install on the device. It works well. So I believe the problem doesn't lie in the code but rather some setting changes I made to the built schema unknowing.

Comment: The answer by @OnikIV is not related to your "ARC semantic" error but _does_ point out another flaw in the code shown (dequeue is called but the result is never used because then it immediately allocs a new one).  For the "ARC semantic" error, can you show the `#import` or `@class` lines the file is using?  Do you by any chance have your _own_ class named `MKPinAnnotationView`?  Did you try cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: I only have annotation classes, not annotationView classes. I've updated the question with the import classes.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[AKNeutralPin class]]) {
     MKPinAnnotationView *neutralPinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"neutral"];
     if(!neutralPinView){
     neutralPinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"neutral"];
    }
     neutralPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
     neutralPinView.canShowCallout = YES;
     return neutralPinView;
}
```

Comment: I tried the code but the same error message still appears when running on device. Works fine on simulator.